# My first Riley riddle, double Riley riddle

Tags: riddle, mathematics, word, wordplay

> My prefix is the 9th.
>
> A prefix of the prefix is a pronoun.
>
> My infix is in many languages, but not in English.
>
> An infix of the infix is another pronoun.
>
> My suffix is a pot.
>
> A suffix of the suffix is a masculine name.
>
> Together, I beg for a dagger.
>
> I doubled, that's the identity.

What am I?

Comment: When an answer is not yet complete, and especially on a weekend, it's often best to wait a bit before accepting the answer even when it's essentially correct; this gives you and the solver some time to get the answer Just Right, and gives others a chance to see your puzzle and the solution--and, naturally, to upvote them :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Almost certain you are a

> Hermitian

My prefix is the 9th.

> Hermit is the 9th Tarot card

A prefix of the prefix is a pronoun.

> Her

My infix is in many languages, but not in English.

> *miti* means myth in Italian, Albanian, Armenian, Azerbaijani, Basque, Bosnian, Bulgarian, etc. (courtesy of Google Translate)

An infix of the infix is another pronoun.

> it

My suffix is a pot.

> tian: an oval cooking-pot

A suffix of the suffix is a masculine name.

> Ian

Together, I beg for a dagger.

> Hermitian is represented by a dagger symbol in mathematics

I doubled, that's the identity.

> The identity could refer to the definition of the [Hermitian transpose](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) where a Hermitian matrix is a complex square matrix that is equal to its own conjugate transpose.

Comment: rot13(Sbe cbg, lbh jnag 'gvna')

Comment: @Rubio Thanks for the tip! I have made more edits for the remaining hints as well